# PHP include is only working in certain places in my custom WP theme

Tags: php, templates, include

I am building a site using a custom WP theme, and I have been using:

```
<?php include('header-bar.php'); ?>
```

in order to include a navigation bar on each page. I intentionally didn't put the navigation in the header.php file because I don't need it on every page.

That bit of code is working fine in certain places, but failing in others.

It works in this scenario:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


  <div class='main-content'>

  <?php include('header-bar.php'); ?>

    <div class='container'>

            <?php 

                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile; endif; 
            ?>
    </div>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but it mysteriously fails in this scenario:

```
<?php 



/*
Template Name: Contact
*/


?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class='main-content'>

  <?php include('header-bar.php'); ?>

    <div class='container'>

            <?php 

                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile; endif; 
            ?>

    </div>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In this second scenario, the page displays properly, except for a the 'header-bar.php' code which is nowhere to be found. The change that I am making that seemingly 'breaks' this line of code is by adding the template name. Can anyone offer some insight into why this may be? I'm baffled.

Thanks in advance! CPR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello CandyPaintedRIMS,

Please try [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function to include any file into your custom template.

**Your code:**

```
<?php include('header-bar.php'); ?>
```

**It should be replaced with:**

```
<?php get_template_part( 'header-bar' ); // include header-bar.php ?>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Thank you

Comment: Yes it did work! Thank you. Do you have any clue why include would work in the other scenarios, but I have to use get_template_part in this one?

Comment: @CandyPaintedRIMS in the top comment block you have `Template Name: Contact` which indicates, that you are in a child theme of `Contact` theme. If the file you are including is not in the child but in the parent theme, simply using `include()` won't work because it only checks the current working dir and include paths. `get_template_part()` on the other hand is aware of the theme hierarchy and checks the parent theme folder too.

Answer (score 1):

For the header, you should use the **[`get_header`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/)** function.

**Your code:**

```
<?php include('header-bar.php'); ?>
```

**Should be replace with:**

```
<?php get_header( 'bar' ); ?>
```

The [**get_header**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) function uses [**locate_template**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) which:

> Searches in the STYLESHEETPATH before TEMPLATEPATH and
>   wp-includes/theme-compat so that themes which inherit from a parent
>   theme can just overload one file.

and also has a fallback to use the default **header.php** file in any situation the specified header can't be found.

Comment: The OP's code shows that `header.php` is already being included before `header-bar.php` is to be included. So falling back to `header.php` and include it a second time is probably not expected behaviour. Therefore I would go with AddWeb's answer.